# Uploading data to a database through html and python

Tags: html, sqlite, flask

For school, I am attempting to construct a basic form to upload data to a database. I am doing this through Flask and I am having issues regarding submitting the data. After filling out the form and submitting I am returned with the error 400 bad request (The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.). Below is the relevant code any suggestions would be appreciated.

HTML:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/add" method="post">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                       placeholder="Charlie" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                       placeholder="Nielsen" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Date</label>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Supervisor</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="supervisor" name="supervisor">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Supervisor Number</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="supervisor_num" name="supervisor_num">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Time Worked</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="unconfirmed_hours" name="unconfirmed_hours">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Service Description</label>
                <textarea name="service_desc" rows="5" cols="55" maxlength='255'></textarea>

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Python:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_service():
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('add_service.html')
else:
    service_details = (
        request.form['firstname'],
        request.form['surname'],
        request.form['date'],
        request.form['supervisor'],
        request.form['supervisor_num'],
        request.form['unconfirmed_hours'],
        request.form['service_desc']
    )
    print(service_details)
    insert_service(service_details)
    return render_template('success.html')

def insert_service(service_details):
connie = sqlite3.connect(db_locale)
c = connie.cursor()
sql_execute_string_a = 'UPDATE student_details SET unconfirmed_hours = unconfirmed_hours WHERE firstname = firstname AND surname = surname'
sql_execute_string_b = 'INSERT INTO service_details (firstname, surname, date, supervisor, supervisor_num, unconfirmed_hours, service_desc) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
c.execute(sql_execute_string_a, sql_execute_string_b, service_details)
connie.commit()
connie.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the disabled on the inputs.

```html
   <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" aria-describedby="emailHelp"placeholder="Charlie" hidden>
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="surname" name="surname" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                       placeholder="Nielsen" >
            </div>
```

Also change their name matching the request.form

Comment: You can use readonly as an attribute instead of disabled if you want the input to be uneditable, also kindly set the value attribute of the input you want to be uneditable.

Comment: Also I highly recommend trying out flask-sqlalchemy it would make your dayabase queries easier and iirc based on my experience sqlite without sqlalchemy sometimes have a problem with 'thread'.

Comment: If it is fixed already, can you accept the answer as the solution by clicking the √ button. Thanks~